# PHP multiple image file upload and storage to folder and database

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a site that will show night revelers a listing of night club establishments and events happening in a big city. I'm trying to build a back-end page where an administrator can be able to add clubs and input information such as establishment name, location, relative pricing etc and of course some images of the club.

Each club will have to have at least one image, the main image. There can be an additional 5 but these are optional, ie. database fields can be null.

I have a form that looks like this:

```
Establishment Main Photo
TextField: name = "establishment_image"

Establishment Photo 1
TextField: name = "establishment_image"

Establishment Photo 2
TextField: name = "establishment_image"

Establishment Photo 3
TextField: name = "establishment_image"

Establishment Photo 4
TextField: name = "establishment_image"

Establishment Photo 5
TextField: name = "establishment_image"
```

Its kinda like the yahoo mail attach file form. As you can see the textfields have the same textfield name for now.

I need to know what kind of changes I need to make on my submit form to be able to: for instance;

Put a main pic and leave other textfields blank,
Put a main pic, pic 1 and 2 and leave other textfields blank,
Put a main pic, pic 1, 2 and 3 and leave other textfields blank etc.

My establishment_submit.php looks like this:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/connections.php'); ?>
<?php //maintain the session
if (!isset($_SESSION))
{
  session_start();
}
?>
<?php 
//retrieve data from Query String
$establishment_name= $_POST['establishment_name'];  
$short_description= $_POST['short_description'];        
$long_description= $_POST['long_description'];      
$location= $_POST['location'];          
$url_link= $_POST['url_link'];  
$establishment_address= $_POST['establishment_address'];        
$establishment_pricing= $_POST['establishment_pricing'];
$establishment_telephone= $_POST['establishment_telephone'];        
$establishment_contact= $_POST['establishment_contact'];
$establishment_email= $_POST['establishment_email'];            
$establishment_image = $_FILES['establishment_image']['name']; 

//escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$establishment_name= mysql_real_escape_string($establishment_name);     
$short_description= mysql_real_escape_string($short_description);       
$long_description = mysql_real_escape_string($long_description);        
$location= mysql_real_escape_string($location);             
$url_link= mysql_real_escape_string($url_link);
$establishment_address= mysql_real_escape_string($establishment_address);
$establishment_pricing= mysql_real_escape_string($establishment_pricing);
$establishment_telephone= mysql_real_escape_string($establishment_telephone);
$establishment_contact= mysql_real_escape_string($establishment_contact);
$establishment_email= mysql_real_escape_string($establishment_email);
$establishment_image= mysql_real_escape_string($establishment_image);

//redirect when successful
$establishmentAddSuccess = "establishment_add_success.php";
?>
<?php
//define a maximum size for the uploaded images
define ("MAX_SIZE","10000");
// note that these dimensions are considered the maximum and are not fixed
// because we have to keep the image ratio intact
//define a maximum size for the uploaded images
define ("LARGE_WIDTH","500");
define ("LARGE_HEIGHT","390");
define ("WIDTH","100"); //set here the width you want your thumbnail to be
define ("HEIGHT","100"); //set here the height you want your thumbnail to be.
// this is the function that will create the appropriately sized images from the upload 
// the resize will be done considering the width and height defined, but without deforming the image

function make_largeimage($img_name,$filename,$new_large_w,$new_large_h)
{
    //get image extension.
    $ext=getExtension($img_name);
    //creates the new image using the appropriate function from gd library
    if(!strcmp("jpg",$ext) || !strcmp("jpeg",$ext))
    $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($img_name);
    if(!strcmp("png",$ext))
    $src_img=imagecreatefrompng($img_name);
    if(!strcmp("gif",$ext))
    $src_img=imagecreatefromgif($img_name);
    //gets the dimensions of the image
    $old_x=imageSX($src_img);
    $old_y=imageSY($src_img);
    // next we will calculate the new dimensions for the large image
    // the next steps will be taken:
    // 1. calculate the ratio by dividing the old dimensions with the new ones
    // 2. if the ratio for the width is higher, the width will remain the one define in WIDTH variable
    // and the height will be calculated so the image ratio will not change
    // 3. otherwise we will use the height ratio for the image
    // as a result, only one of the dimensions will be from the fixed ones
    $ratio1_large=$old_x/$new_large_w;
    $ratio2_large=$old_y/$new_large_h;
    if($ratio1_large>$ratio2_large) 
    {
        $large_w=$new_large_w;
        $large_h=$old_y/$ratio1_large;
    }else
    {
        $large_h=$new_large_h;
        $large_w=$old_x/$ratio2_large;
    }
    // we create a new image with the new dimensions
    $dst_large_img=ImageCreateTrueColor($large_w,$large_h);
    // resize the big image to the newly created one
    imagecopyresampled($dst_large_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$large_w,$large_h,$old_x,$old_y);
    // output the created image to the file. Now we will have the image into the file named by $filename
    if(!strcmp("png",$ext))
        imagepng($dst_large_img,$filename);
    else
        imagejpeg($dst_large_img,$filename);
    if (!strcmp("gif",$ext))
    imagegif($$dst_large_img,$filename);
    //destroys source and destination images.
    imagedestroy($dst_large_img);
    imagedestroy($src_img);
}

function make_thumb($img_name,$filename,$new_w,$new_h)
{
    //get image extension.
    $ext=getExtension($img_name);
    //creates the new image using the appropriate function from gd library
    if(!strcmp("jpg",$ext) || !strcmp("jpeg",$ext))
    $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($img_name);
    if(!strcmp("png",$ext))
    $src_img=imagecreatefrompng($img_name);
    if(!strcmp("gif",$ext))
    $src_img=imagecreatefromgif($img_name);
    //gets the dimmensions of the image
    $old_x=imageSX($src_img);
    $old_y=imageSY($src_img);
    // next we will calculate the new dimensions for the thumbnail image
    // the next steps will be taken:
    // 1. calculate the ratio by dividing the old dimensions with the new ones
    // 2. if the ratio for the width is higher, the width will remain the one define in WIDTH variable
    // and the height will be calculated so the image ratio will not change
    // 3. otherwise we will use the height ratio for the image
    // as a result, only one of the dimensions will be from the fixed ones
    $ratio1=$old_x/$new_w;
    $ratio2=$old_y/$new_h;
    if($ratio1>$ratio2) 
    {
        $thumb_w=$new_w;
        $thumb_h=$old_y/$ratio1;
    }else
    {
        $thumb_h=$new_h;
        $thumb_w=$old_x/$ratio2;
    }
    // we create a new image with the new dimensions
    $dst_img=ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);
    // resize the big image to the newly created one
    imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y);
    // output the created image to the file. Now we will have the thumbnail into the file named by $filename
    if(!strcmp("png",$ext))
        imagepng($dst_img,$filename);
    else
        imagejpeg($dst_img,$filename);
    if (!strcmp("gif",$ext))
    imagegif($dst_img,$filename);
    //destroys source and destination images.
    imagedestroy($dst_img);
    imagedestroy($src_img);
}
// This function reads the extension of the file.
// It is used to determine if the file is an image by checking the extension.
function getExtension($str) 
{
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}
// This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error found)
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures. If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
$errors=0;
// if it is not empty
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['establishment_image']["name"]);$i++)
{
// get the original name of the file from the clients machine
$filenames = stripslashes($_FILES['establishment_image']['name'][$i]);

// get the extension of the file in a lower case format
$extensions = getExtension($filenames);
$extensions = strtolower($extensions);
// if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error, print an error message
//and will not upload the file, otherwise we continue
if (($extensions != "jpg") && ($extensions != "jpeg") && ($extensions != "png") && ($extensions != "gif"))
{
$warning = ("File extension of an image(s) not allowed");
header("location:establishment_add.php?warning=$warning");  
$errors=1;
exit();
}
else
{
// get the size of the image in bytes
// $_FILES[\'image\'][\'tmp_name\'] is the temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
$size=getimagesize($_FILES['establishment_image']['tmp_name'][$i]);
$sizekb=filesize($_FILES['establishment_image']['tmp_name'][$i]);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($sizekb > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
$warning = ("Images have exceeded the size limit of 10MB");
header("location:establishment_add.php?warning=$warning");  
$errors=1;
exit();
}
$rand= rand(0, 100000);
//we will give an unique name, for example a random number
$image_name=$rand.'.'.$extension;
//the new name will be containing the full path where the image will be stored (images folder)
$consname="C:/wamp/www/NNL/Administrator/Establishment_Images/".$image_name; //change the image/ section to where you would like the original image to be stored
$consname2="C:/wamp/www/NNL/Administrator/Establishment_Images/Thumbs/".$image_name;
//change the image/thumb to where you would like to store the new created thumbnail of the image
$copied = copy($_FILES['establishment_image']['tmp_name'][$i], $consname);
$copied = copy($_FILES['establishment_image']['tmp_name'][$i], $consname2);
//localhost calling of images
$img_large="../Establishment_Images/".$image_name; //change the image/ section to where you would like the original image to be stored
$img_thumb="../Establishment_Images/Thumbs/".$image_name;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
if (!$copied) {
$warning = ("Unable to upload image file");
header("location:establishment_add.php?warning=$warning");  
$errors=1;
exit();
}else{
// the new large image will be placed in Images/ folder
$imagelarge_name=$consname ;
// call the function that will create the thumbnail. The function will get as parameters
// the image name, the thumbnail name and the width and height desired for the thumbnail
$imagelarge=make_largeimage($consname,$imagelarge_name,LARGE_WIDTH,LARGE_HEIGHT);
// the new thumbnail image will be placed in Images/Thumbs/ folder
$thumb_name=$consname2 ;
// call the function that will create the thumbnail. The function will get as parameters
// the image name, the thumbnail name and the width and height desired for the thumbnail
$thumb=make_thumb($consname,$thumb_name,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}
}
}
?>
<?php
//If no errors registered, redirect page
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
{
//insert into database
$query2 = "INSERT INTO establishment(establishment_name, 
                            establishment_short_description, 
                            establishment_long_description, 
                            establishment_address,
                            establishment_telephone, 
                            establishment_contact, 
                            establishment_email,  
                            location_id, 
                            establishment_pricing,                          
                            establishment_url_link,
                            establishment_mainphoto_url,
                            establishment_thumb_url) 
                            VALUES  
                            ('$establishment_name',
                            '$short_description',
                            '$long_description',
                            '$establishment_address',
                            '$establishment_telephone',
                            '$establishment_contact',
                            '$establishment_email',
                            '$location',
                            '$establishment_pricing',
                            '$url_link',                            
                            '$img_large[0]',
                            '$img_thumb[0]')";                          
//Execute query
$qry_result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: " . $establishmentAddSuccess);
}
else
{
    $establishment_msg = ("Unable to add establishment");
    header("location:establishment_add.php?establishment_msg=$establishment_msg");  
    exit(); 
}       
?>
```

This worked fine for single image uploads but doesnt work now. I know I need to make changes from the line;

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['establishment_image']["name"]);$i++)
{
```

How do I make this form be able to upload multiple images. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: after all that you just need to know how to upload multiple images? first brush up your searching techniques on this site.

Comment: @Yehonatan. We are not all experts here. From past experience on THIS site, I have seen that if you are not clear and just ask a general question:e.g how do you upload multiple images in PHP? you may not exacly get what you are looking for. I like to show code so people can see exactly what I'm trying to do. Like for Mark B for instance.

Comment: If you look in the top right of this page you'll see a search box. Type "upload multiple images in PHP" and hit return. Check it out, 115 pages of results. If that doesn't help then go ahead and write verbose questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's array notation as you would in regular form fields:

```
Pic 1:  <input type="file" name="establishment_image[]" />
Pic 2:  <input type="file" name="establishment_image[]" />
```

However, the file processing stuff in PHP will handle it a bit differently than you'd expect server-side:

```
$_FILES = array(
    'establishment_image' => array(
          'name' => array(
              0 => 'name of Pic 1 file',
              1 => 'name of Pic 2 file'
          ),
          'error' => array(
              0 => error code for pic1 upload,
              1 => error code for pic2 upload
      etc...
);
```

It's easy enough to handle, though:

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['establishment_image']['name']) as $idx) {
     .... 
}
```

The other option is to give each file input a unique name and work with that serverside. If you hard code a numeric "sub key" in each:

```
<input type="file" name="establishment_image_1" />
<input type="file" name="establishment_image_2" />
```

Then you can simply do

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
     echo "Name of file is ", $_FILES["establishment_image_$i"]['name'];
     ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I will try option 2. Will let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Image upload pages are a lot of brain damage when you consider the quirks of imagick, UI patterns for the upload page, permissions, etc.  My shortcut in a situation where an internal admin is doing the page is [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com).

The admin then uses gallery for upload, resize, cropping, etc.  In essence, the basics plus the "extras" that my clients might demand but that I might not be able to justify charging enough to do from scratch.  On the user-side, I query out the gallery from the MySQL database and arrange in any manner I wish, normally via a flashy JQuery front-end I've rigged up.  But, it could be anything...and I could even use the gallery stock front-end.

Simiplicity-wise, it doesn't get easier for the user to understand.  I can have it up and running in under 2 hours start to finish.  And since images are being stored statically in the file system, there's no more additional load than expected.

If you do opt to go it alone, there's certainly more than one way to attack this challenge.  I'd recommend checking out this popular post:  [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)